# Extract chapter from a pdf, but not the table the of content

Tags: python

Currently I try to extract the Combined Management Report from the following annual report:
https://www.merckgroup.com/content/dam/web/corporate/non-images/investors/reports-and-financials/earnings-materials/2021-q4/en/2021-Q4-Report-EN.pdf

I transformed the pdf into text:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-15044794/MerckKGaA03-MAR-2022FullYear66228323.txt.html

Now I want to extract page 14-228(the whole chapter Management Report and Corporate Governance).

Currently I work with two commands, the first indicating the start position, and the second the "end position".

```
item7_regex=re.compile(r"Combined|Group\s+Management\s+Report",re.DOTALL)
item8_regex=re.compile(r"Consolidated\s+Financial\s*Statements",re.DOTALL)
```

And to extract the code i use:

```
def extract_mdna(plain_text:str, min_mdna_length=25000):
    section_start_match= item7_regex.search(plain_text)
    if section_start_match:
        section_start_pos=section_start_match.start()
        section_end_pos=section_start_pos
        while(section_end_pos<section_start_pos + min_mdna_length) and section_end_pos!=-1:
            section_end_match=item8_regex.search(plain_text,section_end_pos+1)
            if section_end_match:
                section_end_pos=section_end_match.start()
            else:
                section_end_pos=-1
            if section_end_pos>0:
                item7_text=plain_text[section_start_pos:section_end_pos]
                return item7_text
    return None
for x in fileList: 
    pepsi = open(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Research\test\Merck KGaA 03-MAR-2022 Full Year 66228323.txt", 'r',encoding='utf-8').read()
    nur = extract_mdna(pepsi)
    print(nur)
```

It gives me the Table of Content, and not the actual chapter.

I expected that the variable min_mdna length would only consider text which is at least 25000 characters long.

I am open for any suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Could you please elabortate on how to remove head- and footline? I tried  -x 0 -y 0 -W 20 -H 20 but it always yields an empty text file.

Comment: Hey KJ, thank you very much for the explanations and the providing of code. Lastly, is there a way to see the cropped pdf instead of text? I tried to save the cropped new file as a .pdf but could not open it. I am asking because I have around 1k documents which I want to crop and I plan [:'( ] on looking at each one individually.

Comment: K J, thank you very much for your comments! I even think the way pdf2text works is just fine for my use case. I need to do the inspection in txt then, but it still helps A LOT to loop through 1k files and remove headings.